# How to plot an equation with no analytical solution in R?

Tags: r, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, equation

I have been trying to plot an equation in R. The variables are fixed at (for this instance) `a=0.06`, `b=-0.01`, `i=0`, `t=0.005`, `r=0.0025`, `s=0.015` while I intend to vary variable `e`. Some of the functions in the main equations are,

[image: functions]

The equation looks like this,

[image]

I'd ideally like a plot between `Q` and `x` as `e` increases.

```
t = 0.0005
A = 0.06
B = -0.01
r = 0.00025
s = 0.015
i=0


M= function(e) e*A - i*B
N= function(e) t/(1+t*e-t*i)
P= function(e) (s/t)*(1+N(e)*(r+t))
```

I don't know how to proceed. I'd like to maybe create a list of (e, Q, x) where x is the root of the equation for a given `e` and then maybe use interpolation and then plot (Q, x) in R.

Is there a more direct way of plotting x vs Q? If not, what else could I try? Also, if it's easier to do with Mathematica or MATLAB, I'd be keen to know.

Comment: what is x? is it varying? so how many variables are varying? x? e? Q? is this a 3-d plot?

Comment: e is varying, so M, N, P and Q are varying because they depend on e. The rest is fixed. x should vary too. Its going to be a 2-d plot of Q vs x.

Comment: how can it be a 2-d plot yet you have 3 varying variable? x, Q, e? or do you need Q vs X for a given e?

Comment: For a fixed e, you get a (Q, x) coupling. So you can vary e, and plot these values of (Q, x), with x on Y-axis and Q on x-axis. It'll be a 2-d plot of Q vs x.

Comment: How is it that for a fixed e you get Q, x coupling? for a fixed e you get a fixed Q. but x does not depend on e, x can be anything. for a fixed e, you have as many Q as x. unless x depends on e such that for a fixed e you get a fixed x. if that is the case, what is the function of x?

Comment: if you see the equation, x depends on Q through the equation, as well as on r, and N.

Comment: why do you have `x*N` whereas you have `xrN` instead of `x*r*N`?

Comment: No particular reason.

Comment: for which values would you like to plot Qvs x?

Comment: I would like to get x values associated with Q in (0, 10) ideally, which should be accomplished with e values in (0, 1000). The x-values are supposed to have an upper limit, so the graph would hopefully show that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241469/discussion-between-14thtimelord-and-onyambu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t <- 0.0005
A <- 0.06
B <- -0.01
r <- 0.00025
s <- 0.015
i<-0

Q <- function(e){
  N <-  t/(1+t*e-t*i)
  M <- e*A - i*B
  P <- (s/t)*(1+N*(r+t))
  M/P
}


RHS <- function(x, e){
  N <-  t/(1+t*e-t*i)
  M <- e*A - i*B
  P <- (s/t)*(1+N*(r+t))
  Q <- M/P
  V <- exp(-(r+2*N)/x/r/N)
  exp(-1/(x*N)) +  V* (0.5-Q) + Q*V^2
}

LHS <- function(e){
  1 - Q(e)
}


x <- function(e){
  suppressWarnings(sapply(e, \(u)
         optimise(\(x) (RHS(x,u) - LHS(u))^2, 
                  c(-100000, 100000))$min))
}


# assume 
e <- 0.1
LHS(e)
RHS(x(e), e)


#plot:

e <- seq(0, 1000)
plot(x(e), Q(e), ty='l')
```

Comment: Hi, I get an error saying `Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:31:30: unexpected input
30: x <- function(e){
31:   suppressWarnings(sapply(e, \
                                 ^`

Comment: @14thTimeLord what are you trying to run? Copy the code exactly the way it is and run it. There is no error. You can open a new R session and run the code

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I did copy it exactly in a new script, I got the above mentioned error again.

Comment: I have just run @Onyambu's code and it works fine, with no error.

Comment: Alright, It must be a problem on my end. I will restart my server.

Comment: Apologies for this, but I tried the code on these online platforms: http://makemeanalyst.com/run-your-r-code/ , and https://rdrr.io/snippets/, I get the same error there as well. It points to the function definition of x, specifically at sapply(e, \(u) part.

Comment: @14thTimeLord i see what you mean. You are using an older version of R. Please go through the code and any `\ ` that you see, change it to `function` ie instead of `\(u)` change that to `function(u)` etc

Comment: Hi, Could you please expand a little bit on what's happening in the codeline where you define x as a function of e?

Comment: @14thTimeLord given a specific `e` value, there is an `x` value that makes the left hand side ie `1-Q` be equal to the right hand side. what is that x? So you see, x depends on `e`. for each `e` there is a defined `x`. hence `x` is a function of `e`

Comment: I get that. I understand a bit better now. In the "optimize" code we are looking for the x that makes the difference between LHS and RHS as small as possible, for a particular e.

Comment: @14thTimeLord thats right. Once we get that x, we can plot Q vs x. If this solution answers your question please consider accepting it.

Comment: How come the x(e) value is the upper limit that we provided it (100000) for most e values? I am not quite sure if the x- values are coming out right.

Comment: Alternatively, would it be acceptable if I optimized RHS-LHS, instead of optimizing the squared difference?

Comment: @14yhTimeLord. You can use any cost function. Though th l2 is easier to optimize. You can use l1 norm. But cannot use L3 for example. The results must be positive. If you get negative then you cannot minimize the error as it can be -infinity